# Feedback for a programming blog for students

Tags: java, blogs

For my senior independent study project at my University I am working on creating a blog with general programming topics, tutorials, tips and tricks, etc. for a wide variety of languages with the ultimate goal that professors can use it as a tool to help students. My main problem is that I have never actually tried teaching programming, a lot of what I know just came pretty naturally, so I have a hard time figuring out if what I write will be accessible to a college level student with minimal experience in programming while not being too drone for juniors/seniors who are computer science majors. I just finished my first basic tutorial and was wondering if I could get some feedback before sending it to my professor.

http://awestover.blogspot.com/2011/01/minesweeper-in-java-part-one-gui.html

Comment: Its a good one. You have given enough details for understanding the demo app in tutorial. You should go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page was not that hard to follow assuming that someone knows some basic things...

Here is an idea: Use Wordpress so you can have multiple pages

Have the intermediate post on the 1st page with a link to the beginner post for those that need help getting started and an advanced post for those at a higher level.

You can also achieve this in Blogger.com but I have found Wordpress easier to navigate personally.

Comment: I will take look and feel into consideration, but it will not be on blogger permanently, once enough posts get completed and approved it will be moved to the University's web server.